# How do I breakdown the decrypt error when decrypting data to JSON using Node JS?

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

I'm trying to decrypt an encrypted JSON file in NodeJS

How do I go about breakdown the bad decrypt error?

Some information about the data I'm looking to decrypt. Initialization vector is the first 16 bytes of the received data. The payload itself is is the rest of the received data.

```
`purchaseRouter.route('/')
  .post((req, res, next) => {
    var algorithm = encryptionHelper.CIPHERS.AES_128_CBC;
    var originalBase64 = req.body.data.replace(/-/g, "_").replace(/\+/g, 
    "/");
    const key = process.env.ECWID_CLIENT_SECRET.slice(0, 16);
    var decText = encryptionHelper.decryptText(algorithm, key, 
    originalBase64, "base64");
    console.log("decrypted text = " + decText);
   });
```

Below is the error I'm receiving.

```
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured it out. For those who might come across this issue in the future. There was a mistake in my conversion to the original base64.

```
var originalBase64 = req.body.data.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");
```